# How to use gettext to make QML files translatable

Tags: application-development, qt, internationalization, gettext, qml

I'd like to write a [QtQuick](http://qt.nokia.com/qtquick/) app based on Python ([PySide](http://www.pyside.org/)) and [QML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML).

I know Qt apps have got their own translation technology, but I would like to stick to [gettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html) for this one. I'd like to know if it's possible to:

- Mark strings for translation in QML files in a way gettext tools can extract them into a `.pot` file
- Have gettext translate QML files at runtime.

I know this is done in the [Unity 2D code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-2d-team/unity-2d/trunk/view/head:/libunity-2d-private/src/unity2dtr.cpp), in C++, so I'm wondering how it can be done with Python.

Note: I'm talking about using exclusively gettext at runtime, not about converting between gettext and Qt Linguist formats.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking there is no way to use gettext translation in QT because the library uses an internal translation mechanism (Qtranslate and .ts files) as stated here [QTBUG-2404](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-2404).

However, there is a viable alternative.

Shipping with QT there is a toolkit called *lconvert* that can be used to convert .ts files to .po and vice versa.

So you can extract all of your translation with:

`lupdate`

Then use *lconvert* to obtain a po file:

`lconvert -of po -o file.po file.ts`

After translation you can convert back the po file to ts:

`lconvert -of ts -o file.ts file.po`

Then you can use it in your software.

*lupdate* can bu used both for QT an QtQuick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. I'm aware of the conversion tools, but they won't make gettext load the translations at runtime. I know it is technically possible by overriding the Qt translate call, as the Unity 2D guys do it in C++, I'm just trying to figure out how to do it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack the lupdate's source  use something you like to substitute qsTr.  (is easyly)
and then use you hacked lupdate + lconvert + you custome libintl to achieve use gettext objective.

Comment: Explain how please.

Comment: open the qdeclarative.cpp(in lupdte source code) find "qsTr" substitue it with anything you want, assume use "dsTr".
Then use dsTr("you string") in qml.    use lconvert generate an pot file  after use the modifed lupdate to generate an ts file.    
The last you need implement and export the dsTr to global context

Comment: Go head and put that in the answer. Just as a general rule, always tell how and then give source.